# How to handle invalid user input table name

Tags: c#, t-sql

I am writing a C# WinForms program which includes a user input textbox, the value of which will be used to create a table. I have been thinking about what the best way to handle invalid T-SQL table names is (though this can be extended to many other situations). Currently the only method I can think of would be to check the input string for any violations of valid table names individually, though this seems long winded and could be prone to missing certain characters for example due to my own ignorance of what is a violation and what is not.

I feel like there should be a better way of doing this but have been unable to find anything in my search so far. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: SQL Server is highly permissive when it comes to what it allows as a table name (when using `[]` delimiters) perhaps a better option would be to whitelist valid characters and test against that.

Comment: Two points: 1) (as stated by Alex K. already), you can wrap any name in `[]` to make it valid (or use `QUOTENAME()` to let a T-SQL function do this for you) and 2) Don't do this! This smells heavily... It might help to describe what you want to achieve. For sure there are better approaches...

Comment: thanks for your responses. @Shnugo could you explain why it "smells heavily"?

Comment: SQL Server allows `CREATE TABLE [](ID INT)`. There you go, one sparkling heart table. Even control characters are allowed. Whether you *should* allow them is another matter, though. As is the wisdom of allowing users to create tables with a GUI. Are you sure you don't want to define the tables yourself once and for all, and include things like a `UserID` column in rows to distinguish what user the data came from?

Comment: @JeroenMostert the tables are going to be used to store test results, and so needs to create a new table for each test. There is no way of knowing how many tests are going to be carried out. As you can tell I have little experience with sql so any suggestions to better ways of doing this are welcome

Comment: Tables can have any number of rows, so you don't have to know any number in advance. Consider `Tests(ID INT IDENTITY, OtherDetails NVARCHAR(100))` and `TestResults(ID INT IDENTITY, TestID INT, Outcome NVARCHAR(100))`. To start a new test, insert a new row in `Tests`, capture the ID, then insert the result(s) in `TestResults`. No new tables required. If you cannot define the structure of all tables up front, then generally a database is the wrong thing to use. There are exceptions, but you should shoot for a static model if possible -- it makes querying results that much easier.

Comment: Christian, try to explain some more background. Use the edit option of your question. What data will be stored, why don't you know the structure in advance? How are you going to deal with tables, where you don't know the structure?

Comment: @JeroenMostert thankyou I will have a think about doing it how you suggested

Answer (score 2):

As told you in a comment already you should not do this...

You might use something like this

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE dbTest;
GO
USE dbTest;
GO
CREATE TABLE UserTables(ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_UserTables PRIMARY KEY
                       ,UserInput NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_UserInput UNIQUE);
GO
INSERT INTO UserTables VALUES(N'blah')
                            ,(N'invalid !%$& <<& >< $')
                            ,(N'silly ');
GO
SELECT * FROM UserTables;

/*
ID  UserInput
1   blah
2   invalid !%$& <<& >< $
3   silly 
*/

GO
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE dbTest;
GO
```

You would then create your tables as `Table1`, `Table2` and so on.
Whenever a user enters his string, you visit the table, pick the ID and create the table's name by concatenating the word `Table` with the `ID`.

### There are better approaches!

But you should think of a fix schema. You will have to define columns (how many, which type, how to name them?). You will feel in hell when you have to query this. Nothing to rely on...

One approach is a classical `n:m` mapping

- A User table (UserID, Name, ...)
- A test table (TestID, TestName, TestType, ...)
- The mapping table (ID, UserID, TestID, Result VARCHAR(MAX))

Depending on what you need you might add a table

- question table (QuestionID, QuestionText ...)

Then use a mapping to bind questions to tests and another mapping to bind answers to such mapped questions.

another approach was to store the result as a generic container (XML or JSON). This keeps your tables slim, but needs to knwo the XML's structure in order to query it.

Many ways to skin a rabbit...

### UPDATE

You ask for an explanation...

The main advantage of a relational database is the pre-known structure.
Precompiled queries, cached results, statisics, indexes demand for known structures.
Data integrity is ensured with constraints, foreign keys and so on. All this demands for known names, known types(!) and known relations.

User-specific table names, and even worse: generically defined structures, do not allow for any join, or other typical RDBMS operation. The only approach is to create each and any statement dynamically (string building)

The rule of thumb is: Whenever you think to have to create several objects of for the same, but with different names you should think about the design. It is bad to store `Phone1`, `Phone2` and `Phone3`. It is better to have a side table, with a UserID and a `Phone` column (classical `1:n`). It is bad to have `SalesCustomerA`, `SalesCustomerB`, better use a `Customer` table and bind its ID  into a general `Sales` table as FK.

You see what I mean? What belongs together should live in one single table. if you need separation add columns to your table and use them for grouping and filtering.

Just imagine you want to do some statistical evaluation of all your user test tables. How would you gather the data into one big pool, if you cannot rely on some structure in common?

I hope this makes it clear...

If you still wnat to stick to your idea, you should give my code sample a try. this allows to map any silly string to a secure and easy to handle table name.

Comment: Still doesn't explain the reason it is bad to allow the user to name the tables? or is it just because you don't want to have many different tables

Comment: @ChristianT *or is it just because you don't want to have many different tables*... No, a good database will consist of very many tables. But each table stands for a given content. It is just bad to use many different tables to store what is the same...

Answer (score 0):

Lots can go wrong with users entering table names. A bunch of whacked out names is maintenance nightmare. A user should not even be aware of table name.  It is a security risk as now the program has to have database owner authority.  You want to limit users to minimum authority.

Similar to Shnugo but with composite primary key.  This will prevent duplicate userID, testID.

```
 user 
 ID int identity PK 
 varchar(100) fName 
 varchar(100) lName

 test 
 ID int identity PK 
 varchar(100) name

 userTest 
 int userID  PK FK to User
 int testID  PK FK to Test 
 int score 

 select t.Name, u.Name, ut.score 
 from userTest ut
 join Test t 
   on t.ID = ut.testID 
 join User u 
   on u.ID = ut.userID 
 order by t.Name, u.Name
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but what if a user may take a test more than once? if one thinks about this deeply, you'd need several more tables like `testsession` with a `UserID` and a `DateTime`. Then you'd bind this SessionID to the `userTest`... In this case uniqueness seems to be an overkill...

Comment: @Shnugo And what if you don't want a user to take a test more than once?

Comment: This is  business logic and should - in most cases - not be handled by such a strict constraint. The sooner or later - for sure! - someone will ask to repeat a test :-D

Comment: To answer your question: I'd rather set an unique index on the pair of IDs. This can be removed rather easily...

Comment: @Shnugo  Maybe they will ask to repeat.  If the rule is you cannot repeat then this works.   Can we just let the OP consider the options.   I don't have a question here.

Comment: Thankyou for your answers they have helped me. I don't want to mark as the answer however as it is not an answer to my original question - which might make it confusing for people with similar questions

Comment: @ChristianT About your *I don't want to mark as the answer however as it is not an answer to my original question*. Since you've crossed the 15 points yourself, you are asked to vote. It is kind to say *thank you*, but the SO-way to say thx is an upvote. Btw: I do not understand your reason not to accept. Your question is answered, but not in the way you might have expected this...

Comment: @ChristianT You need to be careful of the XY problem.  Asking question of a perceived solution rather stating the problem at hand.  You should still include what you have tried but it gives people a chance to tell you that you are going down the wrong path.